# Calling stored procedure using OUT parameter with Spring Spring JPA 2.*

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am calling a stored procedure using IN parameter - it's working fine.

```
public interface ABCRepository extends JpaRepository<ABC, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="exec p_NextSequence :clazName , 1")
    Integer  callSequenceForClaz(@Param ("clazName")String clazName);
}
```

Need help how to do it for OUT parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer below link for how to call a stored procedure.

https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 1):

Simply define method annnotating it with Stored Procedure name, Map input param of stored Procedure with method parameters, Map output param of SP as the return type of the method, Example.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeJPA extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
@Procedure(procedureName = "enroll_employee_program")
public String enrollEmpProgram(Long employeeId, Long programId,  LocalDate createdDate, String createdBy);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Procedure used on a repository

```
@Procedure(procedureName="SP_MP_LOG_CONSULTA",outputParameterName="response")
```

int called(@Param("name") name);

I had to use the outputParameterName --> cause it was giving me an out undefined column error.

Comment: Adding concise code would help here. This is useless

Answer (score 0):

Encontre este ejemplo que me funciono, saludos
@Procedure(procedureName = "con_nombreSP", outputParameterName = "out_parameter")
public double nameMethod (@Param ("in_param") double param,
@Param ("in_param2") double param2,
@Param ("in_param3") int param3);

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).